# Accessing property using string

Tags: typescript

What's proper way to access interface/class properties using strings?

I have following interface

```
interface Type {
  nestedProperty: {
    a: number
    b: number
  }
}
```

I'd like to set nested property using array iteration like that:

```
let myType:Type = ...
["a", "b"].forEach(attributeName => myType.nestedProperty[attributeName] = 123)
```

TS complains that "nestedProperty" doesn't have string index type. If I add if typeguard (e.g. `if (attributeName === "a"))` compiler is happy but I really don't want to go `if (...===... || ...===... || ... ) {`  route.

I also don't want to use indexed type:

```
interface Type<T> {
  [index:string]: <T>
  a: <T>
  b: <T>
}
```

Since it's not dynamic structure and properties could have different types.

I'm sure there is some elegant way to do it but can't seem to find it anywhere in documentation/Stack Overflow/web.

Should I write custom guard returning union type predicate for that? 
Something like that?

```
(attribute: string): attribute is ('a' | 'b') { ... }
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether your `Type` interface was just a generic example. If it isn't, you can go with `interface Type {nestedProperty: {[key: string]: number};}`

Comment: Yeah. That was one of "solutions" but I don't want `Type` to be dynamic structure where I can put anything there. I want to stick to set of defined properties. I've edited question to be more precise

Comment: And what about `interface Type {nestedProperty: {[key in ('a' | 'b')]: number};}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell TypeScript that the array you're using consists only of the properties allowed as keys in the `nestedProperty` property.

```
interface Type {
  nestedProperty: {
    a: number
    b: number
  }
}

// Create a type alias for convenience. The type itself
// is a list of keys allowed in the `nestedProperty`.
type NestedAccessors = Array<keyof Type['nestedProperty']>

// Now TS is happy to do anything with the list since it
// can guarantee you're using proper values.
(["a", "b"] as NestedAccessors).forEach(attributeName => myType.nestedProperty[attributeName] = 123)
```

Comment: `keyof`! Haven't seen that one in documentation yet :) Looks really clean. Thank you very much. TypeScripting for few days so far. Totally in love. Now even more :)

Comment: As a follow up: Is there a way to turn NestedAccessor to array so I could just go with `NestedAccessorsSomeHowTurnedIntoArray.forEach( accessor => ... )`?

Comment: You can't access interfaces in the run-time, after the app is compiled to JavaScript. The best you can do is to access properties of the existing object that implements the Type interface. `const arr = Object.keys(myType.nestedProperty) as NestedAccessors` will get the key values and then you can do `arr.forEach(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with:

```js
interface Type {
  nestedProperty: {[key in ('a' | 'b')]: number}  
}

let myType:Type = {
    nestedProperty: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
    }
};

(["a", "b"] as Array<'a'|'b'>).forEach(attributeName => myType.nestedProperty[attributeName] = 123)
```

Given the problem, if you don't wanna declare an additional type, this could be a way. But I like the things more explicitly declared, like in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for showing some extra "type fun" :) Also casting during access looks okay-ish: `myType.nestedProperty[attributeName as keyof Type['nestedProperty']] = ...`